# How could I write the following expression without expanding it?

Tags: combinatorics, limits

in a induction proof I stumbled over the following situation:

$$\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{2n}}\left(-m\right)^k\left(n^2+nm+n+m\right)^{n-k}$$

The degree of the numerator is always smaller as the degree of the denominator.. so this limit goes to zero for every piece of the sum..

(I expanded it for some terms to check if this statement is indeed true or atleast should be)

How could I rewrite the sum, so that its clean and visually pleasing to see that all the pieces of the sum go to zero?

Thanks alot :)

Edit:

I came from here:

$\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{m+1}{n}\right)^n=\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{(n+1)(n+m)}{n^2}-\frac{m}{n^2}\right)^n=\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)-\frac{m}{n^2}\right)^n$

$=\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\sum\limits^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}\left(-\frac{m}{n^2}\right)^k\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)^{n-k}$

$=\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}\left(-\frac{m}{n^2}\right)^k\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)^{n-k}+\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)^n$

$=\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}\left(-\frac{m}{n^2}\right)^k\left(\frac{n^2+nm+n+m}{n^2}\right)^{n-k}+\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)^n$

$=\lim\limits_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{2n}}\left(-m\right)^k\left(n^2+nm+n+m\right)^{n-k}+\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)^n$

Comment: Well, it looks like what you have is vaguely related to the binomial expansion in some way. Maybe factor out the $n^{-2n}$ and start from there?

Comment: If I add the first term for k=0 this converges tho

Comment: to e^m ....:D kinda why i pulled it out

Comment: Why do you want to do this? $\left(1+(m+1)/n\right)^n$ is a much simpler expression to work with.

Comment: If your sum is $S_n$ then you have $(1+\frac{m+1}{n})^n = S_n+((1+\frac{1}{n})(1+\frac{m}{n}))^n$.  The left term converges to $e^{m+1}$ and the rightmost term to $e\times e^m$.  So $S_n$ converges to zero.

Comment: But thats what I want to proof in the first place

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure but it looks like you're making the following commonly made mistake. Consider the limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1n+\frac1n+\cdots+\frac1n\right) $$
where the sum has $n$ terms. We have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/n)=0$ so each term has limit $0$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1n+\frac1n+\cdots+\frac1n\right)=0+0+\cdots+0=0$$
But this is wrong. The sum is just $n\cdot\frac1n=1$, so it's limit is $1$. You can't generally do this unless the number of terms is constant, i.e. it doesn't depend on $n$. On the other hand, in this example and in your problem we have dependence on $n$.

Comment: So in my form of the limit, I cannot proof what I wanted to proof?

Answer (score 0):

$n^2+nm+n+m
=n(n+m)+n+m
=(n+m)(n+1)
$
so the sum is

$\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^{2n}}\left(-m\right)^k\left((n+m)(n+1)\right)^{n-k}\\
=\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\left(\frac{m}{n^2}\right)^k\left(\frac{(n+m)(n+1)}{n^2}\right)^{n-k}\\
=\sum\limits^n_{k=1}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\left(\frac{m}{n^2}\right)^k\left((1+m/n)(1+1/n)\right)^{n-k}
$

Are these any better?

Comment: Hmm yeah thats the form I came from :/ with the first element (startting from k=0) w get the series which converges to e^m. so i pulled the first out to close my induction.. Is it clearly visible that this converges to zero?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the argument "all the pieces of the sum go to zero" is that as $n$ increases, you keep getting new pieces, and you never stop getting new pieces.

I think you would need to prove that the whole sum goes to zero, not just individual pieces of it.

What if you back up to the last expression before you applied the binomial theorem and try something like this instead?

$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac mn\right) - \frac{m}{n^2}
= \left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac mn\right)
  \left(1 -  \frac{m}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac mn\right)n^2} \right).
$$

Now if you can prove that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} 
\left(1 -  \frac{m}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)\left(1+\frac mn\right)n^2} \right)^n
= 0,
$$

I think the rest of the proof follows easily.

Comment: Hmm I cant really follow your idea :/